# Facebook with DotNetOpenAuth 4.1.0.12182

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I'm attempting to create a user login for Facebook and Windows LiveId using **DotNetOpenAuth 4.1.0.12182**

However the examples in the download make use of `DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock` and `DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock.Facebook` which don't exist in the current build.

Instead there is the `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients` namespace which includes `FacebookClient` and `WindowsLiveClient` - however I can't find any example of how to use these.

**Do any examples or documentation exist?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have been able to get DNOA version 4.1.0.12182, .Net 3.5 and Facebook to work with each other by creating a FacebookAuthClient that is derived off of the DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient. One little gotcha that I have found is that if you are using cookie based sessions then you have to access the session before you use the OAuth functionality. From what I can tell this is because DNOA uses the Session ID as the state parameter and if session has never been accessed it can change between requests. This will cause a state parameter mismatch error when the response comes back from Facebook.

FacebookAuthClient:

```
public class FacebookAuthClient : DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient
{
    private static readonly DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServerDescription Description = new DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.AuthorizationServerDescription
    {
        TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"),
        AuthorzationEndpoint = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize")    
    };

    public static readonly string [] ScopeNeeded = { "publish_stream" };

    public FacebookAuthClient()
       : base(Description)

    {
    }
}
```

Facebook.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class FacebookPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private FacebookAuthClient _client = new FacebookAuthClient
    {
        ClientIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBClientId"], //The FB app's Id
        ClientCredentialApplicator = DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FBClientSecret"]) // The FB app's secret
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.IAuthorizationState auth = _client.ProcessUserAuthorization();
        if (_auth == null)
        {
            // Kick off authorization request with the required scope info
            client.RequestUserAuthorization(FacebookAuthClient.ScopeNeeded);
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a test app so there is no error handling but it seems to work.

**Edit**
I used the DotNetOpenAuth(unified) NuGet package for all of this.

**Edit**
Added missing .PostParameter call to the creating of the ClientCredentialApplicator.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Josh - I just wish it didn't involved a SO bounty to bring this into the light! (Not aimed at you or anyone)

Comment: `DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientCredentialApplicator` says it is a type, but I can use `.NetworkCredential` from it. But then I get error 400 bad request.

Comment: BrunoLM - Thanks for pointing that out I have updated the code with to DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter. Notice the PostParameter part that was missing

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use ctp version 3.5 of DNOA. Version 4+ has been made to work with a later draft of OAuth 2 then Facebook uses.

You can find it on the owners GitHub:
https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid

Comment: If this is the case, then why does the `FacebookClient` class exist in the library?

Comment: I've had quite a lenghty discussion about this with the creator of DNOA, he pointed out that is due to the fact that it will probably be working later on when Facebook decides to up to the newest draft. Until then there is no other solution, except handle the requests yourself.

Comment: It would be very useful if there was an prominent FAQ on DNOA about this (other other) issues. DNOA goes a long way to simplifying using OpenID/OAuth - but issues like this introduce fresh questions